# Installing Gatsby plugins breaks entire app

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

Whenever I install any gatsby plugins or typography files, and then attempt to run `gatsby develop`, I am thrown an error sying that 'react' can't be found. Example:

I create a new gatsby site using `gatsby new example-site https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world`

I install the gatsby-plugin-sass using `npm install --save node-sass gatsby-plugin-sass`

I follow the instructions on the plugin page, adding the plugin to my gatsby-config.js file.

When I now attempt to run `gatsby develop` I receive the following errors:

> ERROR
>
> There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"? Cannot find module 'react'
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'react'

As well as a list of files that the errors are being thrown in, most of them in internal files.

Clearly I have the Gatsby-cli installed, as well as react. I'm also receiving a ton of warnings about deprecated related to core-js and optional dependencies not being installed.

In my research, I have found people saying that using yarn instead of npm solves the issue, but with Gatsby being as large of a project as it is, and with the documentation itself saying to use npm, that doesn't seem like a solution but rather a work around. Is there any other info on this that I just can't seem to find?

Comment: What happens when you run `npm install` in your project directory? Any errors there? (also note that `gatsby-cli` is not the same as the `gatsby` dependency. You need the second to run a Gatsby project)

Comment: When running npm install, I don't receive any outright errors, just several warnings about files not being removed because they weren't installed by other node-modules,  and then warnings about skipping optional dependencies. 

Also, when running `gatsby -v` I am shown both a cli version and a gatsby version as well. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reprodued your error, and after looking around I found [several](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19064) [issues](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19064) on the Gatsby GitHub repo with the same behavior.

It seems that this is a problem with npm itself, which is why the community is increasingly switching to yarn.

If you'd like to stick with npm, the solution is to clear your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then reinstall your dependencies ([source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19064#issuecomment-547552008)):

```sh
rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Yea that was all I was able to find myself, and deleting the modules and lock file with each plugin was tiresome, so I switched to yarn myself. Thank you for taking the time to look into and confirm my findings.